# how to manipulate string on the basis of occurrence of characters and index of character. ex: 'tree' to 'eert'

Tags: python, string

"tree" to "eert" as 'e' occured twice and among 'r' and 't', as 'r' is of higher index so that will come first.

```
    Was able to get the occurence of each character and clubbed same occurance characters together



def stringFunction(mystr):
    mydict = {}
    for i in range(len(mystr)):
        if mystr[i] in mydict:
            mydict[mystr[i]] = mydict.get(mystr[i]) + 1
        else:
            mydict[mystr[i]] = 1


    print(mydict)   
    print(set(sorted(mydict.values())))

    final_list = []
    for each in set(sorted(mydict.values())):
        print(each)
        listOfKeys = []
        listOfItems = mydict.items()
        for item  in listOfItems:
            if item[1] == each:
                listOfKeys.append(item[0])

        print(listOfKeys)
```

Output of above code was

```
{'r': 1, 'e': 2, 't': 1}
set([1, 2])
1
['r', 't']
2
['e']
```

Expected result = "eert"

Comment: can you share a few more examples to make this more clear..?

Comment: sure. apple  = ppela
    
    deer = eerd

Comment: Pass lambda function to key of sort. First create something like `[ (a, wrd.count(a), i) for a in enumerate(wrd)]` where `wrd` is your word as list of letters. Should be able to just use the word directly but I’ve not tested this

Answer (score 4):

save the word, frequency of word and rank/index of the word in a list. then sort the list by the order first frequency and then the index value (in solution i didn't reverse it). once result is get, get the character from the last element to first element (if not reversed , else if reverse then get it from first element to last element).

```
def func(st):
        #storing word , word count , word index in a tuple and 
        # then stroing this all in a list     
        l =[(i,st.count(i),st.index(i)) for i in set(st)]       

        # sort the list in reverse order on the base of frequency of word
        # and then index value of word i
        l.sort(key=lambda x:[x[1],x[2]],reverse=True)

        # finally joining the word and no of times it come ie if p come 2 time 
        # it become 'pp' and append to final word
        return ''.join([i[0]*i[1] for i in l])



print(func("apple"))  # ppela
print(func("deer"))   # eerd
print(func("tree"))   # eert
```

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
from collections import Counter

def stringFunction(mystr):
    return "".join(n * char for n, char in Counter(reversed(mystr)).most_common())

print(stringFunction("apple"))  # ppela
print(stringFunction("deer"))   # eerd
print(stringFunction("tree"))   # eert
```

where [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is used to count the number of occurrences of the letters and the `reverse`ing takes care of the order of the letter that occur the same amount of times.

---

if you really want to avoid imports you could do this (this will only generate the correct order in python >= 3.5):

```
def stringFunction(mystr):
    counter = {}
    for char in reversed(mystr):
        counter[char] = counter.get(char, 0) + 1

    ret = "".join(
        n * char
        for char, n in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    )
    return ret
```

Comment: it fails for this case:
`print(stringFunction("tree"))  #Expected : eert # Obtained : eetr` and also for the case "deer"

Comment: You can check by yourself. It still fails to provide the expected outcome for `deer` and `tree`

Comment: @taurus05 yes you are right. i do not understand the logic behind the order... do you? what does 'higher index' mean?

Comment: It is not even clear to me as well. I am actually trying to figure out..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195901/discussion-between-taurus05-and-hiro-protagonist).

Comment: ok higher index means..... in the example of tree..... index if r = 1 and t = 0 so r will come first... hence eert

Comment: @nname thanks for the clarifications. that is what i achieve with `reversed`, right?

Comment: true but am looking for answers without using inbuilt functions :)

Comment: what are the "inbuilt functions" you want to avoid? (i am not using anything that is not in your python interpreter). you are using `set` and `range` and `dict`...

Comment: hmm..like 'from collections import Counter'

Comment: ok, added a variant. is there a reason you do not want this import? you sacrifice a lot of convenience and speed.